# If $f_n\to f$ in measure, is there a subsequence s.t. $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f_n\to f$ in measure, is there a subsequence s.t. $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e. ? The convergence in measure is a little be abstract to me, I don't really see what it means (even if I know the definition). So I have difficulties to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

If $f_n\to f$ in measure then $|f_n-f|\to 0$ in measure. So let prove that if $g_n\to 0$ in measure, then there is a subsequence $g_{n_k}\to 0$.

It's in fact a consequence of Borel-cantelli lemma. You have by definition that $$m\left(|g_n|>\frac{1}{p}\right)\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0$$
for all $p\in\mathbb N$. So fix $p\in\mathbb N$. There is $k_p$ s.t. $$m\left(|g_{k_p}|>\frac{1}{p}\right)<\frac{1}{2^p}.$$

Therefore $$\sum_{p\in\mathbb N^*}m\left(|g_{k_p}|>\frac{1}{p}\right)<\infty $$
and thus by Borel-Cantelli, $$m\left(\limsup_{p\to\infty }\left\{|g_{k_p}|>\frac{1}{p}\right\}\right)=0,$$

what prove the claim.

**Convergence in measure**

You have that $f_n\to f$ if $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \lim_{n\to \infty }m\{x\in\mathbb R\mid |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\varepsilon \}=0$$
so the convergence in measure is a weakness convergence.

Comment: very nice answer. Maybe though choose a different symbol for $m \in \mathbb N$, since $m$ already is our measure? :)

Comment: You are right, I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you :-) So does it mean that $f_n\to f$ in measure if $m\{x\mid \lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)\}\neq 0$ ?

Comment: The last paragraph is simply wrong? Whatever this is it has noting to do with convergence in measure.

Comment: @T'x: Indeed, I corrected it... (I don't know why I wrote that 2 years ago). Thank you for pointing this mistake.